# Show a div when a cookie exists in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, getelementbyid

I want a div to show when a visitor has a cookie and hide when the cookie is not present. I know the cookie is being detected but for some reason, the display part of getElementByID is not working.

I have tried to start with #protectd {display:none.} in a small style sheet in the header and my javascript to change it to block if a cookie is detected.
I have tried to set the display to none right after the div is identified.
I know I must be missing something. The commented out section was for testing the cookie part.

```html
<script>

    const elem = document.getElementById("protected");
    elem.style.display = "none";
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("pointsuser") != -1) {
        // Show the element here.
        //document.write("<p>Cookie is here</p>");
        elem.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        // Hide the element here.
        //document.write("<p>Cookie is NOT here.</p>");
        elem.style.display = "none";
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Not using a console. Just testing in the browser.

Comment: I mean the browser's console in Developer Tools.

Comment: debug: `const elem = document.getElementById("protected"); console.log(elem, document.cookie.indexOf("pointsuser") != -1);`

Comment: I am getting an error on line 12 which is the elem.style.display = "none"; It says it is: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Answer (score -3):

It's possible that the JavaScript code is executed before the DOM has finished loading, which means that the getElementById function cannot find the element with the ID "protected".

Here is an example of how you can modify your code:

```
window.onload = function() {
  const elem = document.getElementById("protected");
  elem.style.display = "none";
  if (document.cookie.indexOf("pointsuser") !== -1) {
    elem.style.display = "block";
  } else {enter code here
    elem.style.display = "none";enter code here
  }
};
```

Comment: Most or all of your six answers here appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.